# GCC ppc64 aligned functions

Tags: alignment, powerpc

I'm using GCC for make some powerpc64 executable, but sometimes between functions i have the following mistakes: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdWcx.png)

Powerpc instructions format are still in 4 bytes, i tried some gcc commands (-fno-align-functions) but the compiler still fill bytes between functions.

I want my functions start directly after the end of the previous functions, without any values/zero filled (in the case of the screenshots the functions should start at 0x124).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The PPC64 ABI specifies a traceback table appended to functions.  The zeroes may be due to the traceback table and not related to alignment.  Try using the 
`-mtraceback=no` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the traceback table issue noted in the previous answer, functions are normally aligned on a 16-byte boundary.  This is important for various reasons, including so the compiler can align hot loops on a 16-byte boundary for improved icache performance.  Assembly code from GCC will have a directive like:

.p2align 4,,15

before each function definition to enforce this.  So even without the traceback table your function will not start at address 0x124 without more effort.

This behavior can be overridden using -fno-align-functions, or using optimization level -Os (optimize for size).  I've tried both methods, and they both remove the .p2align directive.  Using -fno-align-functions is preferable unless you really want smaller and potentially slower code.

(If you are compiling with -O0 or -O1, you won't see the directive either, but we do not recommend compiling at such low optimization levels for either size or speed.)